# Adding a question repeating filter using hive for my quiz app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm making a quiz app and I am now faced with an issue of same questions repeating for a quiz. I wanted to implement hivebox in the sense that every question has a single unique question number named *qnumber*, if the hivebox has *qnumber* of a certain question that question will not show in the next question.

The clauses for clearing said hive box are:

1. if selected number of questions < number of questions with *qnumber* in hivebox, get  remaining questions that have not been asked yet+ (clear hivebox) any other questions to fill the requirement for selected number.
2. if total question = total question in hive box, then clear hivebox

Other than these I don't think any other reset clauses are needed.
Now no matter what I do I'm unable to implement this.

Here is a single question from *quiz.json*

```
{
    "category": 9,
    "type": "multiple",
    "qnumber": 1,
    "difficulty": "any",
    "question": "Which of the following is a programming language? any1",
    "correct_answer": "Python",
    "incorrect_answers": ["Latin", "Swahili", "Mandarin"]
  },
```

Here is *quiz_data.dart*

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../model/question.dart';

Future<List<Question>> getQuestionsFromJson(
    {int? categoryId, int? totalQuestions}) async {
  final String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/quiz.json');
  List<dynamic> json = jsonDecode(data);

  if (categoryId != null) {
    json = json.where((result) => result['category'] == categoryId).toList();
  }

  if (totalQuestions != null && json.length > totalQuestions) {
    json.shuffle();
    json = json.sublist(0, totalQuestions);
  }

  return json.map((result) {
    return Question(
      category: result['category'],
      type: result['type'],
      qnumber: result['qnumber'],
      difficulty: result['difficulty'],
      question: result['question'],
      correctAnswer: result['correct_answer'],
      incorrectAnswers: List<String>.from(result['incorrect_answers']),
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

Here is *question_provider.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/model/question.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/service/quiz_data.dart';
import '../DataManagementSystem/question_box.dart';

class QuestionProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late List<Question> listQuestion;
  late bool isLoading;
  late String error;
  late int currentIndex;
  late Map<int, dynamic> answer;

  final questionBox = QuestionBox();

  void initValue() {
    listQuestion = [];
    isLoading = false;
    error = '';
    currentIndex = 0;
    answer = {};
  }

  Future<List<Question>> getDataQuestion(
      String difficulty, int totalQuestion, int categoriesId) async {
    try {
      await questionBox.init(); // Initialize the QuestionBox
      final List<int> askedQuestions = questionBox
          .getAskedQuestions(); // Load the asked questions from the Hive box
      listQuestion = await getQuestionsFromJson();
      listQuestion = listQuestion
          .where((question) =>
              question.difficulty == difficulty &&
              question.category == categoriesId &&
              !askedQuestions.contains(question.qnumber))
          .toList(); // Filter out the questions that have already been asked
      listQuestion.shuffle();
      listQuestion = listQuestion.sublist(0, totalQuestion);
    } catch (e) {
      error = 'Unable to read data';
    }
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return listQuestion;
  }

  void selectRadio(dynamic e) {
    answer[currentIndex] = e;
    notifyListeners();
    return;
  }

  void selectQuestion(dynamic e) {
    currentIndex = e;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void previousQuestion() {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      currentIndex--;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> submitQuiz(List<Question> listQuestion) async {
    if (currentIndex < (listQuestion.length - 1)) {
      currentIndex++;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void isLoadingg(bool status) {
    isLoading = status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is *quiz_bottomsheet.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/model/question.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/provider/question_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/screen/quiz_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/util/constant.dart';
import 'package:flutterquiz/widget/snackbar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class QuizBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int id;

  const QuizBottomSheet({Key? key, required this.title, required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizBottomSheetState createState() => _QuizBottomSheetState();
}

class _QuizBottomSheetState extends State<QuizBottomSheet> {
  int selectNumber = 10;
  String selectDifficult = "Any";
  late String selectType;
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(40), topRight: Radius.circular(40)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Select Total Number of Questions"),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildNumberQuestion(10),
                _buildNumberQuestion(20),
                _buildNumberQuestion(30),
                _buildNumberQuestion(40),
                _buildNumberQuestion(50),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Select Difficulty"),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Any"),
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Easy"),
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Medium"),
                _buildDifficultQuestion("Hard"),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Center(child: Consumer<QuestionProvider>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, QuestionProvider value,
                  Widget? child) {
                // add "?" to "Widget"
                return value.isLoading
                    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                    : Visibility(
                        visible: value.isLoading ? false : true,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => _startQuiz(value),
                          child: Text(
                            "Start Quiz",
                            style: kHeadingTextStyleAppBar.copyWith(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
              },
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildNumberQuestion(int number) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectNumber = number;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(5, 5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(-5, -5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Color(0xffb8bfce).withOpacity(.1),
            ),
          ],
          color:
              selectNumber == number ? kItemSelectBottomNav : Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        child: Text(
          number.toString(),
          style: selectNumber == number
              ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
              : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildDifficultQuestion(String difficult) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectDifficult = difficult;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 70,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(5, 5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              offset: Offset(-5, -5),
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Color(0xffb8bfce).withOpacity(.1),
            ),
          ],
          color: selectDifficult == difficult
              ? kItemSelectBottomNav
              : Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            difficult,
            style: selectDifficult == difficult
                ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _startQuiz(QuestionProvider value) async {
    if (selectDifficult != null && selectNumber != null) {
      value.isLoadingg(true);
      List<Question> listQuestion = await value.getDataQuestion(
          selectDifficult.toLowerCase(), selectNumber, widget.id);

      if (listQuestion.length < selectNumber) {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text(
                "Not enough questions available for the selected category and difficulty"));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        value.initValue();
      } else {
        value.initValue();
        Navigator.pop(context); // close show bottom sheet
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => QuizPage(
              difficult: selectDifficult,
              id: widget.id,
              listQuestion: listQuestion.take(selectNumber).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        elevation: 5.0,
        content: Text(
          'Please choose option!',
        ),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is *int_adapter.dart*

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class IntAdapter extends TypeAdapter<int> {
  @override
  final typeId = 0; // Assign a unique ID to the adapter

  @override
  int read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return reader.readInt();
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, int obj) {
    writer.writeInt(obj);
  }
}
```

Finally here is the code for the hivebox

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class QuestionBox {
  static const String _boxName = 'questionBox';
  static const String _key = 'askedQuestions';

  late Box _box;

  Future<void> init() async {
    _box = await Hive.openBox<int>(_boxName);
    print('QuestionBox initialized');
  }

  List<int> getAskedQuestions() {
    final List<int> askedQuestions = _box.get(_key, defaultValue: []);
    return askedQuestions;
  }

  Future<void> addAskedQuestion(int qnumber) async {
    final List<int> askedQuestions = getAskedQuestions();
    askedQuestions.add(qnumber);
    await _box.put(_key, askedQuestions);
    print('Added qnumber $qnumber to askedQuestions: $askedQuestions');
  }

  Future<void> clearAskedQuestions() async {
    await _box.put(_key, []);
    print('Cleared askedQuestions');
  }
}
```

I want to implement hivebox for that every question has a single unique question number named *qnumber*, if the hivebox has *qnumber* of a certain question that question will not show in the next question, but this implementation is returning the error "not enough question....." despite there being enough questions.